# When a APNS token got expired ? iOS/ Push

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, push, pushsharp

I am facing a strange situation. I am testing a web app, aimed to send push notifications. It uses **PushSharp** nuget package.My test is based on sending a little bunch of push messages, to concrete devices. I know that, some of them don't have the app installed.
There are some cases, that APNS doesn't answer with **DeviceSubscriptionExpired**, mostly whith the firsts attemps.
After a while, it correctly starts to answer with the proper **DeviceSubscriptionExpired**

1. How APNS works  ?
2. When it marks a device token as expired? In which
   situations?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apple notification service respond to your push request with status code https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html

```
Status code  Description
0            No errors encountered
1            Processing error
2            Missing device token
3            Missing topic
4            Missing payload
5            Invalid token size
6            Invalid topic size
7            Invalid payload size
8            Invalid token
10           Shutdown
255          None (unknown)
```

For an expired token it's possible return 8. The process is asynchronous, and it may take a while to get status feedback.